# When should I add/remove observers of UIApplication Notifications?

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

When should I add and remove observers of UIApplication notifications?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveState) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadState) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Is this bad? I am only interested in notifications when the view is on the screen. And would it be any problems with removing the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in the `viewWillDisappear:` method? I am thinking about the order in which things happen...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in `- (id)init{}` or another matching initializer, and `- (void)dealloc{}` instead. Adding and removing observers in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear would unnecessarily do it multiple times when you're presenting and dismissing modals, for example.

For projects with ARC, you can still implement the dealloc method. Just don't call `[super dealloc]` like you did with Manual Retain/Release projects. In fact, the compiler won't let you.